# performance: connecting to the Redux store vs passing data through props

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm using the redux store for all my major components, but for smaller components, I've just been passing down regular react props. Which is more efficient?

If  have many smaller components, does it make any difference to pull from redux or pass down in regular props?

The [Redux docs](https://redux.js.org/faq/performance/) says:

> many individual components should be connected to the store instead of just a few

This sounds like I should be connecting even my smaller (sometimes very tiny) components too. Currently, I am using the store in many, but not all, components.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`connect`ing smaller components is more performant because when Redux state changes, only the affected components will rerender. Passing down regular React props is less efficient because when state changes, that change gets passed through many nested components down to the small component, causing all those components to rerender.

While connecting small components is more performant, it comes with some drawbacks described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37108790/is-connect-in-leaf-like-components-a-sign-of-anti-pattern-in-reactredux). To summarize, connecting a component couples it to the Redux state. So, the component must be tested with a store, and the component can't be modular unless store implementation goes with it. The solution to this is to separate a component's stateful logic from its stateless logic.

```
const StatefulTodo = ({ id }) => {
  const todo = useSelector(state => getTodo(state, {id});

  return <StatelessTodo {...todo} />
}
```

```
const StatelessTodo = ({ ...todo }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{todo.title}</p>
      <p>{todo.description}</p>
      ...etc
    </div>
  )
}
```

With this approach, a `Todo` UI can communicate application state while being decoupled from the state, testable in isolation, and reusable.

In practice, you should decide which components to connect given the tradeoffs. A perceivably performant app doesn't have to prevent every possible unneeded rerender. And you can always use the React devtools profiler to see which components need to be optimized.

Comment: It's only connected to a store if you only export the connected component--which isn't what should be done. Export the component, connect it where it's used--not where it's defined. Or export both, this makes it easier to test, and more versatile.